# Downloading attachments bigger than 25MB using imaplib in gmail

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I'm looking for a way to download attachments from gmail that are bigger than 25MB and therefore Gmail doesnt attach them but it inputs a link to download them in the email. So how could I change the following code to make it extract in someway the link and download the file?

```
def download_attachments_in_mailbox(self):
    # Note: This function definition needs to be placed
    #       before the previous block of code that calls it.
    rv, data = self._M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print "No messages found!"
        return

    for num in data[0].split():
        rv, data = self._M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
            return

        mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        for part in mail.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                # print part.as_string()
                continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                # print part.as_string()
                continue
            fileName = part.get_filename()

            if bool(fileName):
                filePath = os.path.join(detach_dir, fileName)
                if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
                    print fileName
                    fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                    fp.close()
```